# Databricks autocomplete configuration

Tags: pyspark, autocomplete, databricks

Each time I want to see the available methods in Databricks I also see the name of the object. Because of this, I am not able to select what I need. So, My question is if there is a way to configure the autocomplete to not see the object, to see only the methods or whatever (like it was for example in Databricks Community).

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As of today, it's not a configurable feature even in paid editions.